# How to add decimal point to decimal number in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add 0.10 to 23.50 but I get 23.50.10 instead of 23.60

## my code

```
console.log((parseFloat(23.50) + parseFloat((Math.random() * 0.10) + 0.01).toFixed(2)));
```

This piece of code generates decimal point like: 0.04, 0.29, etc...

```
parseFloat((Math.random() * 0.90) + 0.01).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: Side note: You don't need (or want) to `parseFloat` something that's **already** a number.

Comment: `toFixed(2)` returns a string.  Adding that to a number becomes string concatenation.

Comment: Do all the arithmetic first, and use `toFixed(2)` at the end when you want to show it.

Comment: instead of `parseFloat((Math.random() * 0.10) + 0.01)` could it be that you mean `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1) / 100`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.toFixed` is in the wrong parenthesis.

try

```
console.log((parseFloat(23.50) + parseFloat((Math.random() * 0.10) + 0.01)).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: if I want to ask a question for which I need suggestion. How to ask in stackoverflow?

Comment: You may wish to look at the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see if the question is on topic for this site, otherwise I would advise finding the appropriate stackexchange site. [ref](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254567/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-dont-fit-or-are-off-topic-for-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 2):

You have `.toFixed(2)` in the wrong place. The result of that creates a string which is then being concatenated. It should look like this:

```
console.log((parseFloat(23.50) + parseFloat((Math.random() * 0.10) + 0.01)).toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Consolidating the comments:

As [Scott Sauyet said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43398293/how-to-add-decimal-point-to-decimal-number-in-javascript/43398364#comment73857413_43398293), `toFixed` is in the wrong place. You end up with `number + string`, which converts the number to string and does string concatenation.

As [I said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43398293/how-to-add-decimal-point-to-decimal-number-in-javascript/43398364#comment73857410_43398293): That's not the only problem. You don't `parseFloat` something that's **already** a number. Do so converts the number to string, then parses that string as a number, which is at best pointless. :-)

As [Barmar said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43398293/how-to-add-decimal-point-to-decimal-number-in-javascript/43398364#comment73857438_43398293): Do the calculation, then use `toFixed` on the result:

```
console.log((23.50 + (Math.random() * 0.10) + 0.01).toFixed(2));
```

Also, `+` is lower precedence than `*`, so you don't need those inner parens (or the last `0` on `0.10`):

```
console.log((23.50 + Math.random() * 0.1 + 0.01).toFixed(2));
```

...though of course, you could include them for style reasons if you liked.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a typo but your .toFixed() is in the wrong spot. It's translating yourparseFloat((Math.random() * 0.10) + 0.01) to string before the addition to parseFloat(23.50) resulting in string concatenation.

Perform the add and then .toFixed():

```
console.log((parseFloat(23.50) + parseFloat((Math.random() * 0.10) + 0.01)).toFixed(2));
```

Or be extra cautious and use a var:

```
var foo = parseFloat(23.50) + parseFloat((Math.random() * 0.10) + 0.01);
console.log(foo.toFixed(2));
```